# How to replace every second occurence of a word in a text file

Tags: unix, replace

In a file called `sample.txt`, I have the following text:

> Once there is a tortoise and a rabbit. The rabbit was fast, tortoise was slow. 
>   Rabbit used to mock the tortoise. Once the rabbit challenged the tortoise for a race. 
>   Tortoise accepted rabbit’s request. Rabbit was overconfident.
>   Rabbit thought to win the race. Rabbit ran fast. Then rabbit got tired. Rabbit wanted to take rest. So rabbit slept under the tree. 
>   Tortoise kept going and won the race.

How to replace every second occurrence of `rabbit` to `hare` using Unix commands?

Comment: That's a bit underspecified. What about Rabbit with a capital R? And what have you tried so far? We don't want to do your assignment :-)

Comment: I have tried this command { $ sed 's/rabbit/hare/2' sample.txt }. But as you said Rabbit with R is being unaffected.

Comment: Help me with that!

Comment: Thanks for your company jens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the input is one line (or you are happy to count from 1 at the beginning of each line), and want to ignore the uppercase Rabbit, you can use this solution:
First replace all rabbits by one character that `sed` can match.
Replace the second rabbit-characters and restore the other rabbits.

```
sed -r 's/rabbit/\r/g; s/(\r[^\r]*)\r/\1hare/g; s/\r/rabbit/g' sample.txt
```

**Edit, Additional explanation:**
When the input file is a clean unix-style file (no MS-DOS endings \r\n), we know that the character `\r` is unique. After `sed -r 's/rabbit/\r/g` each rabbit is represented by `\r` (the letter `r` actually isn't short the first letter of `rabbit` but the first of `return`).
Now you want to look for sequences `<rabbit><not-a-rabbit><rabbit>`, in our new notation that is the sequence `\r[^\r]*\r`, where `[^\r]*` stands for any sequence of characters without the rabbit character.
When we found 2 rabbits, we want to remember the first rabbit with the non-rabbit characters. In `sed` you can remember a matched sequence with `\(..\)`, or use the option `-r` and `(..)`. You can recall the first memory location (we only have one here) with `\1`, in this case the first rabbit `\r` and the non-rabbit characters. The second rabbit `\r` is replaced by `hare`.
After replacing the second `\r` (global on the line, so every second one), we want to transform the `\r` rabbits  into the string `rabbit`.

**More possibilities**
When your inputfile has more than 1 line, you might want something different. With one rabbit on the first and one rabbit on the second line, how can you catch the second rabbit? Before performing the above `sed` command, you need to transpose your input file to 1 line. Afterwards you want to restore the line-endings, so you will need to replace the line-endings with a special character. Normally I would use the `\r` for this, but that character is reserved for the rabbits. The character `\v` is possible to, resulting in

```
tr '\n' '\v' < sample.txt | 
   sed -r 's/rabbit/\r/g; s/(\r[^\r]*)\r/\1hare/g; s/\r/rabbit/g' | 
   tr '\v' '\n'
```

When you also want to replace uppercase Rabbits, we can transpose those Rabbits in `\a`.
You can ask for any rabbit (large or small) with `[\r\a]`, what will make the command one level more complex:

```
tr '\n' '\v' < sample.txt | 
sed -r 's/rabbit/\r/g; s/Rabbit/\a/g; 
        s/([\r\a][^\r\a]*)[\r\a]/\1hare/g;
        s/\r/rabbit/g; s/\a/Rabbit/g' |
tr '\v' '\n'
```

When you want to replace the uppercase Rabbit `\a` with an uppercase `Hare`, the command will get even more complex (you need another special character).
I want to use the `\x01` for marking a [Rr]abbit to be changed.

```
tr '\n' '\v' < sample.txt | 
   sed -r 's/rabbit/\r/g;
       s/Rabbit/\a/g;
       s/([\r\a][^\r\a]*)([\r\a])/\1\x01\2/g;
       s/\x01\r/hare/g;
       s/\x01\a/Hare/g;
       s/\r/rabbit/g; s/\a/Rabbit/g' |
tr '\v' '\n'
```

Comment: Can you please explain whats happenning here (s/(\r[^\r]*)\r/\1hare/g;)

Comment: Wonderful explanation!! Thanks for your company.

Answer (score -1):

$ sed 's/[Rr]abbit/hare/2' sample.txt