# Print data in file between pattern1 and pattern2 without printing pattern2

Tags: regex, sed

So, I have some data that looks like this:

```
[SVP_VERSION_2]  
D:\CTD\01906932_2019_12_01\01906932_2019_12_01.svp  
Section 2019-335 10:55:14 18:53:56 -93:36:43  
0001.00 1539.85  
0002.00 1539.90  
0003.00 1539.83  
0004.00 1540.03  
Section 2019-335 10:55:14 18:53:56 -93:36:43  
0001.00 1540.05  
0002.00 1540.05
```

I want to print the data from the first "Section" to the line before the 2nd "Section" Like so:

```
Section 2019-335 10:55:14 18:53:56 -93:36:43  
0001.00 1539.85  
0002.00 1539.90  
0003.00 1539.83  
0004.00 1540.03
```

I know I can use:

```
sed -n '/Section/,/Section/p' file
```

to get:

```
Section 2019-335 10:55:14 18:53:56 -93:36:43  
0001.00 1539.85  
0002.00 1539.90  
0003.00 1539.83  
0004.00 1540.03  
Section 2019-335 10:55:14 18:53:56 -93:36:43
```

but I want to strip off the trailing "Section" line. I also know that I can pipe the output to a second sed to delete the last line, but I'm hoping to only make one call to sed. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^Section/{:a;p;n;//q;ba}' file
```

Unset implicit printing `-n` and on matching a line beginning `Section` print that line and the following lines until another line matching the same pattern.

All lines before one beginning `Section` will be disregarded because the implicit printing has been switched off. Once a line beginning `Section` is matched the commands between `{` and `}` are executed.

Firstly a place holder `:a` is established. Then the current pattern space is printed `p`, the next line replaces the current pattern space by the introduction of `n` (it does not print line that is replaced because `-n` prevents this) and this line is checked to see if it matches the last regexp `//q` and if it does all processing is terminated (the `q` command ensures this). If it does not match the command `ba` sends the command flow back to the place holder `:a`.Thus all lines from the line beginning `Section` upto but not including the next line beginning `Section` are printed and then no further processing is done.

The alternative solution below achieves the same result but without using the `-n` switch, here the `d` command deletes any lines before one beginning `Section` and the `Q` command quits the processing without printing the current line (which would be the second occurrence of a line beginning `Section`).

Alternative:

```
sed '/^Section/{:a;n;//Q;ba};d' file
```

Comment: I would appreciate if you add any URL explaining what is `:a` ,`Q`,`ba` etc ?thanks

Comment: @monk `ba` is just the same as `b a`, and it means `b`ranch to (i.e. go to) the line labeled by `a`, and `:a` is the way you label a line with `a`. As regards `Q` (GNU extension) it acts like `q` (POSIX), except that the former does not print the pattern space before quitting, whereas the latter does. This means that the first solution works irrespective of wether you use `q` or `Q`, as `-n` is preventing the printing in the first place. In the second solution the use of `Q` instead of `q` prevents the printing of the second line matching `^Section`.

Comment: @monk sed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info) for more sed info.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand some of what's going on... Sed -n suppresses printing lines... /^Section searches for Section at the beginning of a line. :a drops a label at that location, p prints that line, n goes to the next instance of Section at the beginning of a line... What the HECK does //q do? I assume ba goes back to the first instance of Section at the beginning of the line?

Comment: @SamAlleman `//q` use the last regexp and if it matches quit processing.

Comment: so the p only prints the first matching line, correct? Then 'n' goes to the next matching line and 'q' tells it to stop processing if the current line matches the regexp? and then ba goes back to the first match. What mechanism causes sed to print the lines between the two matches? I've tried looking through various sources of sed documentation, and I'm still at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

When you only have two lines with `Section` and GNU `sed`, you can use

```
sed -rz 's/.*(Section.*)Section.*/\1/' file
```

Comment: Very interesting solution! Does `-z` mean that the whole file is read a single line?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis `-z, --null-data    separate lines by NUL characters`, you can match newlines with `\n`.

Comment: I've read it from the `man`, but it's still not clear to me. Furthermore, you mention `\n`, but you're actually matching new lines with `.`. Can you please help me understand it?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis In this case I could do without matching with `\n`,  in other cases it could help (look for line `key=value` after line `[setting]`). For plain input `sed` will act as if it was one single line. Without this option I often did something like `tr '\n' '\r' | sed 'some command' | tr '\r' '\n'`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50271921/3220113 for an example with rabbits.

Comment: It should be noted that `.*` matches the longest match and if there were other `Section`'s it would bypass them and only match the last.

Comment: @potong Yes, that's why I wrote the restriction "When you only have two lines...". With more Sections my answer fails and your answer works.

Comment: Thank you all so much! My data at the moment contains exactly two sections, but I like knowing how to work with multiple sections. I will spend the next day or two trying to work out how your solutions work. :)