# Using grep with a negative lookahead assertion

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have exactly the same question as in this post, however the regex isn't working for me, in bash. [RegExp exclusion, looking for a word not followed by another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375045/regexp-exclusion-looking-for-a-word-not-followed-by-another)

I want to include all lines of a csv file that include the word "Tom", except when it's followed by "Thumb".

- Include: Tom sat by the seashore.
- Don't include: Tom Thumb sat by the seashore.
- Include: Tom and Tom Thumb sat by the seashore.

The regex `Tom(?!\s+Thumb)` works when I try it out on regex101.com.

But I've tried all these variations and none of them work. What am I missing and how can I work around this? I'm on a Mac.

`cat inputfile.csv | grep Tom(?!\s+Thumb) > Tom.csv`
`cat inputfile.csv | egrep Tom(?!\s+Thumb) > Tom.csv`
`cat inputfile.csv | egrep “Tom(?!\s+Thumb)” > Tom.csv`
`cat inputfile.csv | grep -E Tom(?!\s+Thumb) > Tom.csv`
`cat inputfile.csv | grep -E “Tom(?!\s+Thumb)” > Tom.csv`

Comment: Note that `grep -E` only guarantees ERE syntax. `\s` is PCRE; it may or may not work depending on which specific version of `grep` you're using. And `?!` isn't, to my knowledge, supported in _any_ ERE implementation at all.

Comment: (Some platforms have a `grep` that supports PCRE, but you'll need to check `man grep` on your specific target OS; typically, it's `grep -P` to enable the feature).

Comment: Also, note that `grep` is not part of bash -- it's a separate tool, built by a different team, compiled to a different executable. bash does have its own mechanism to access standard C library regex functionality, but when you use grep, you aren't using bash's regex support -- you're using grep's instead.

Comment: Also, note that the code copied/pasted into the question uses `“` and `”`. These are not recognized as valid quotes by bash. You **must** use only regular double quotes -- `"` -- for them to be recognized as shell syntax. If some software you use has "smart quotes" turned on, be sure to turn them off before using that program to edit shell scripts.

Comment: That said, the "Tom and Tom Thumb sat by the seashore" example indicates that you need a more powerful tool than `grep -E`.

Comment: (Note that just knowing that you're on a Mac doesn't tell us what version of `grep` you have, because Mac users can install their own versions of grep with tools like Nix, Macports, or Homebrew -- listed in my personal descending order of preference)

Comment: ...for example, once you've [installed Nix](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#sect-macos-installation), you can use `nix run nixpkgs.gnugrep -c grep -P ...` to use GNU grep for only a single command line, without changing your system-wide default. (Nix also provides mechanisms to change the software loadout used while working on a specific project; or for a specific user account; or so forth).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex lookahead for 'not followed by' in grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197814/regex-lookahead-for-not-followed-by-in-grep)

Answer (score 9):

**You can't do this with POSIX ERE.**

There is no negative lookahead assertion in [POSIX extended regular expressions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions), which is the syntax `grep -E` activates.

The closest you can get is to combine two separate regexes, one positive match and one negative:

```
grep -we 'Tom' inputfile.csv | grep -wvEe 'Tom[[:space:]]Thumb'
```

`grep -v` *excludes* any line that matches the given expression; so here, we're first searching for `Tom`, and then removing `Tom Thumb`.

However, the intent to match `Tom and Tom Thumb sat by the seashore` makes this unworkable. In short: You can't do what you're asking for with standard `grep`, unless it has `grep -P` to make your original syntax valid. In that case you could use:

```
grep -Pwe 'Tom(?!\s+Thumb)' <inputfile.csv >Tom.csv
```

---

**One hack might be a temporary substitution**

Assuming you have `uuidgen` available (it appears to be present in Big Sur) to generate a temporary, unpredictable sigil:

```
uuid=$(uuidgen)
sed -e "s/Tom Thumb/$uuid/g" <inputfile.csv \
  | grep -we 'Tom' \
  | sed -e "s/$uuid/Tom Thumb/g" >tom.csv
```

Comment: The trouble is, this excludes "Tom and Tom Thumb sat by the seashore", which I want to keep.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. See the extension, which was underway as you added the comment.

Comment: What version of `grep` do you have? Does it have a `grep -P` argument available?

Comment: (The version number isn't actually enough to know if it has a `-P` argument, insofar as that argument is an extension that's only enabled when GNU grep is compiled against libpcre, which is an optional library dependency; all versions that support it can be compiled either with the library -- and thus the option -- or without it).

Comment: Consider installing GNU grep with one of the package managers I suggested in a comment thread attached to the question. Or you can use the hack at the end of the answer with two `sed`s, one before and one after the `grep`.

Comment: Thanks. It's version 2.5.1. `-P`doesn't seem to be included.

Comment: I do have uuidgen available, and tried that method, but the output file is empty. Thanks, will try installing another version of grep.

Comment: Can you show me how you tried to deploy the `uuidgen` method, in enough detail that I can reproduce your problem? It works perfectly in the online interpreter at https://ideone.com/i1d1Cb

Comment: When you have a csv-file without special characters, you might use `\v`. In https://stackoverflow.com/a/50271921/3220113 I used a bunch if special characters, I think `\r`  can occur in a csv file. `sed -e "s/Tom Thumb/\v/g" ...`.

Comment: @WalterA, makes sense as a replacement for the uuid, but I don't believe uuidgen is actually responsible for the OP's problem -- we'd see different symptoms, not an empty output file, if it were.

Comment: @gemma, ... Honestly, if I had to guess what was wrong, my guess would be a topographic error around the line breaks (it's critical that there be no whitespace after each trailing backslash, for example). If you made it all one line like `uuid=$(uuidgen); sed -e "s/Tom Thumb/$uuid/g" <inputfile.csv | grep -we 'Tom' | sed -e "s/$uuid/Tom Thumb/g" >tom.csv`, does that work?

Comment: (ugh; meant `typographic`... how did I make that mistake without a phone's autocorrect? Granted, I do sometimes post from a phone, but the above comment is a pretty gnarly one to type that way).

Comment: I'm using Grep in BBEdit and your answer made me realise I was overthinking it! I already have a grep code to find the lines I want but was trying to invert the search token using negative lookahead. Instead of a negative lookahead all I needed to do was replace the found lines with themselves and not anything else! Thx x1M.

Answer (score 3):

How about a `Perl` solution:

```
perl -ne 'print if /Tom(?!\s+Thumb)/' inputfile.csv > Tom.csv
```

`Perl` obviously supports `PCRE` and pre-installed on Mac.

- The `-n` option is mostly equivalent to that of `sed`.
  It suppresses the automatic printing.
- The `-e` option enables a one-liner by putting the immediate code.
- The code `print if /pattern/` is an idiom to print the matched line, which
  may substitute `grep` command.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Good to know it works. If you feel my answer
solves well your problem, I'd appreciate if you can accept my answer by
clicking on the check mark beside the answer. BR.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple and just use awk, e.g. using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '{orig=$0; gsub(/Tom Thumb/,"")} /Tom/{print orig}' file
Include: Tom sat by the seashore.
Include: Tom and Tom Thumb sat by the seashore.
```

Answer (score 2):

Grep can use Perl regular expressions (PCRE).  From `man grep`:

> -P, --perl-regexp
>
> Interpret PATTERNS as Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCREs).  This option is experimental when combined with the -z (--null-data)  option, and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.

Comment: This is the most direct answer to the OP's question; maybe wiith a little caveat about cross-distro compatibilities. I mean you can just replace 'E' with 'P' in their latter examples

Comment: Not every copy of grep, and not even every copy of _GNU_ grep, has this feature; it's a compile-time option that adds a dependency on libpcre.